Node TCP/HTTP keepalive connection receiving UV_EOF
I'm testing out some logic that requires a kept-alive connection. If I spin up a trivial server (using connect) it works as expected - I receive N requests over a single connection.
However, when I try using the exact same client code to call a simple handler embedded in a more complex application (that still uses the same version of connect and node, running on the same OS) I get N requests over N connections.
I've already checked the obvious:

the Connection: keep-alive header is being received, and set in the response
the timeout (all of them) is reasonable and larger than the request, response or processing time

I dug into this quite deep and found the "cause" is something (on the server) calling onStreamRead with nread=UV_EOF which then closed the connection - though interestingly the client didn't emit a close event until the timeout was hit.
In the simple server where it works, I only receive the UV_EOF when I explicitly close the client (as expected) - in the complex embedded case where it doesn't work, I receive that "immediately" (though not synchronously) after ending the HTTP response. The "something" is in the C code of the TCP handler and not something I can debug. My understanding is that it will be invoked in this way when something tries to read a closed stream. More accurately, that callback should be invoked whenever anything reads from the stream, and despite receiving and processing a small payload, it never gets called except in the UV_EOF condition.
I've looked throughout my app code, and through as much of the (significant) library code I can see, there's nothing I can find that I can think would cause this.
Is there something obvious I've missed?

a flag in node/connect that would kill connections
some common handler/middleware that attempts to read a connection past its end

What approaches are there to further debug this?

I've already tried calling debug on all the relevant (readStart, readStop, shutdown, close, asyncReset, setKeepAlive) methods of the TCP handle - they all get triggered after the UV_EOF has been emitted.


TCP keep-alive and HTTP keep-alive are completely different things. Your title is about TCP keep-alive, your question body seems to be about HTTP keep-alive. And HTTP keep-alive is just a signal of the client that the server might keep the connection open for more requests. The server might still close the connection after a HTTP response was sent and is not required to wait for more requests.

This is for sure a murky area for me - but I guess my question still stands, why would two very similar servers, running on the same hardware with the same load exhibit totally different behaviour here? Particularly given that neither server seems to explicitly be calling the TCP keep alive - one server consistently disconnects, the other consistently does not

Unfortunately there are not enough detail to debug the issue. You only mention that the servers are "similar" - which means they are not the same. Thus the solution to your question probably lies in how they are different - what this exactly is.

Ah, unfortunate - one of them is a full blown application, so determining how they are meaningfully different will be almost impossible - I was really hoping there was an obvious "this happens when XYZ, you need this flag" or some such
